# Cannot refresh list view after delete the row

Tags: flutter

When I delete the data on the row, there are no changes after doing the delete, but when I return the menu to the dashboard page and open to the new Customer Data page, the changes are visible. Here I have given setState so that the list view can be refreshed immediately, but after I give setState it still can't be refreshed. And then an error like the following appears.
[image]

My problem on link https://youtu.be/gC0P-k-2myw

This is mystatefullwidget.

```
class DataNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataNasabahState createState() => _DataNasabahState();
}

class _DataNasabahState extends State<DataNasabah> {
  String nama_debitur = '';
  List<Nasabah> _nasabah = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadUserData();
    _getNasabah();
  }

  _loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        nama_debitur = user['nama_debitur'];
      });
    }
  }

  _getNasabah() {
    NasabahService.getUser().then((nasabah) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _nasabah = nasabah;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Data Nasabah'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff151515),
        // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: 10,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'ID Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Nama Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Aksi',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
          ],
          source: NasabahDataTableSource(
            userData: _nasabah,
            context: context,
            onUserDeleted:(){
              setState(() {
              });
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

class NasabahDataTableSource

```
class NasabahDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  BuildContext context;
  Function onUserDeleted;
  NasabahDataTableSource({this.context, this.userData, this.onUserDeleted});
  final List<Nasabah> userData;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "${userData[index].id}",
            ))),
        DataCell(Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("${userData[index].nama_debitur}"),
        )),
        DataCell(
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          DetailNasabah(
                            nasabah: userData[index],
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                          content: Text(
                              'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                child: Text('Yes'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
                                  onUserDeleted();
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Full Source Code

```
class DataNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataNasabahState createState() => _DataNasabahState();
}

class _DataNasabahState extends State<DataNasabah> {
  String nama_debitur = '';
  List<Nasabah> _nasabah = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadUserData();
    _getNasabah();
  }

  _loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        nama_debitur = user['nama_debitur'];
      });
    }
  }

  _getNasabah() {
    NasabahService.getUser().then((nasabah) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _nasabah = nasabah;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Data Nasabah'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff151515),
        // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: 10,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'ID Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Nama Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Aksi',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
          ],
          source: NasabahDataTableSource(
            userData: _nasabah,
            context: context,
            onUserDeleted:(){
              setState(() {
              });
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NasabahDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  BuildContext context;
  Function onUserDeleted;
  NasabahDataTableSource({this.context, this.userData, this.onUserDeleted});
  final List<Nasabah> userData;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "${userData[index].id}",
            ))),
        DataCell(Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("${userData[index].nama_debitur}"),
        )),
        DataCell(
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          DetailNasabah(
                            nasabah: userData[index],
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                          content: Text(
                              'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                child: Text('Yes'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
                                  onUserDeleted();
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

i haven't find that solution. Please help.

code snippet

**api.dart**

```
  deleteData(apiURL, id) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
    await _getToken();
    return await http.delete(
      fullUrl,
      headers: _setHeaders(),
    );
  }
```

**nasabah_service**

```
static Future<List<Nasabah>> deleteUser(id) async {
    final response = await Network().deleteData(baseUrl, id);
    List<Nasabah> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: I think you missing keys in your code. Check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: Can you also share deleteUser() function, is it a http request? Also onUserDeleted(). And did you tried userData.refresh()?

Comment: @aoiTenshi I have uploaded the code snippet API.DART and NASABAH_SERVICE.DART this is function deleteUser

Comment: Your deleteUser() function is a HTTP request and returns a Future. You should call it in your onPressed with await. Make your onPressed async and await for response like this:
onPressed:() async{
  await NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
}
This may not solve your problem but this is how you should handle requests. You should wait for response. Give it a try.

Comment: @aoiTenshi With that command still doesn't solve the problem, I hope all friends can help

Comment: @AzmiBadhi'uzZaman So, in your deleteUser() you just delete user from your db or something, right? I didn't see if you delete the item from your list like dataList.remove()...

Comment: @Try change `setState` in `onUserDeleted` by `_getNasabah()` to upadate your nasabah data. May not solve the problem, just for updating data.

Comment: @aoiTenshi Yes right, can you help me to modify my source code so that the list can be deleted?

Comment: Based on your error log. Check your code on `nasabah_service.dart` line 22 and 27.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Bro can you give me example source code ?

Comment: @AzmiBadhi'uzZaman Yes, you are not updating your list. Either you should remove item from your list or call the get function as mentioned. It solved right?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Can you help me for this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QoT.jpg

Comment: @aoiTenshi Can you help me for this error ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QoT.jpg

Comment: @aoiTenshi yes it solved, but there is still an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QoT.jpg . can you help me ?

Comment: Your `deleteUser` function return a list. But I don't see where is used for. Based on your error log, I think the error is on `parseResponse`. Try comment/disable code `//List<Nasabah> list = parseResponse(response.body);` and change `return list` to `return [];` on `deleteUser` function. Let me know if the error is exists or gone.

Comment: is the error gone?

Comment: No the error is solved, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your updated List after delet user.

so we can do

```
  onPressed: () async {
                  await  NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
                      .then((value) async {
                    await //NasabahService.getUser();
                  });
                },
```

Comment: .then "Expected an identifier"